# How to prove or disprove there is a unique solution to this linear system where the variable are constrained to the interval [0,1].

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Be $m$ and and $n$ integers such that $1\leq m \leq n$.

Be $l_k$ variable with $dom(l_k)=[0,1]$.

Take the folowwing linear equation system:

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} l_k =1$

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} k\cdot l_k = m$

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} k^2 \cdot l_k = m^2 $

I want to prove that the only solution of such a system is $l_m = 1$ and $l_k=0\quad \forall k\neq m$. This is equivalent to proving there is a unique solution to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz implies
$$\left(\sum k^2\cdot l_k\right)\left(\sum l_k\right)\geq\left(\sum k\cdot l_k\right)^2$$
The equality holds iff. $k^2\cdot l_k=\lambda l_k$ for some $\lambda$ and all $k$. I.e., $l_k=0$ or $k^2=\lambda$. Since the latter equation cannot hold for more than one $k$, the conclusion follows.